# Eclipse SWT 3: What widget to use to get a drop down menu with tool tips on each item?

Tags: eclipse, drop-down-menu, combobox, swt, tooltip

I'm working on an Eclipse SWT application, version 3.

It has an SWT Combo ( I can't use another GUI API ) as a drop down menu.

When the drop down menu is clicked it expands into a list of choices.

I would like for a tool tip to pop up for each menu item as the user mouses over it.

Googling around, I see that the SWT Combo class really doesn't do that.

However, I noticed that when I am in the Eclipse ( version 3.8 ) editor I get something very close to what I want when I type a "." on an object.   I get a scrollable list/menu, where if I click on an item I get a nice tool tip.

What SWT widget is that?

Can anyone point me to an example of how to set something similar up for my own application?

Can I get the widget to go compact like a drop down menu?

If "yes" to all of these things is there an example somewhere showing how to put the tool tips into an xml or text file?

Comment: That isn't a single SWT widget. It is code in the Eclipse editor support which uses a number of controls. The editor code is very elaborate and would not be easy to use in just a SWT app.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you refer to is called *content assistant* in Eclipse. The basic widgets it is built upon is a `Shell` that holds a `Table`, i.e. the ' scrollable list' and another `Shell` positioned alongside that acts as the tooltip.

As [greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) commented, it is used within the editor. But most of the infrastructure is located in JFace and thus should be possible to be used with a standalone SWT application.

The 'scrollable list' is managed by class `ContentAssistant` and the 'tooltip' is referred to as the `ContextInformationPopup` .

However, the `ContentAssistant` is meant to work together with an `ITextViewer`. Using these classes in a different environment may require some extra work or you may be able to adapt the relevant code to fit your needs.